# How to move an armature in an "arm curl" like manner

Tags: python, blender

I am currently trying to figure out how to move an armature like this picture below:
[Armature Example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFko6.png)
because I have done something similar but I was just wondering if there is a method or way of doing it that I may have to take into account:

Also here is the code that I used for my script in python but I am not getting the desired results that I want.

```py
import bpy

#Very Experimental code above 

#This part move the LArm bone
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(-0.0482102, 0.0114472, 0.0880355), constraint_axis=(False, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1.61051)
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(-0.305557, 0.0572005, 0.432175), constraint_axis=(False, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1.61051)
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(-0.418317, 0.065683, 0.488198), constraint_axis=(False, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1.61051)
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(-0.0400046, 0.0210943, 0.168067), constraint_axis=(False, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1.61051)

#This part rotates the LArm bone
    w =  3.055
    x = -0.600
    y = 0.400
    z = -0.518
    Subject = "LArm"
    bpy.context.object.pose.bones[Subject].rotation_quaternion[0] = w
    bpy.context.object.pose.bones[Subject].rotation_quaternion[1] = x
    bpy.context.object.pose.bones[Subject].rotation_quaternion[2] = y
    bpy.context.object.pose.bones[Subject].rotation_quaternion[3] = z
    bpy.context.object.pose.bones[Subject].lock_rotations_4d = True
    bpy.context.object.pose.bones[Subject].lock_rotation_w = True
```

Also I would rather have an explanation of how to move it in that desired position, not so much a breakdown of the code I am using however if that is the case then go right ahead and clarify the reason as to why it would solve the issue.

Hopefully there isn't any confusion what I am trying to ask, but if there is please tell me and I will try my best to solve this issue.

Also, if it isn't much trouble could someone add the tag "armature" if possible, thanks.

Never mind I solved the issue It was as simple as fixing the w and z values

Comment: What do you think the tag description should contain? Are there other questions about this topic?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, the answer to that questions are 1. The bones with armatures in blender or something along those lines or maybe something that deals or relates with the usage of armatures and the like 2. I have made many questions relating to armatures and if I could be a bit presumptuous, I would believe that if I am posting questions about armatures there has to be a possibility of other who are either unsure about armatures or are having some worries of the way that they are using these items within blender and maybe also, there might be people who have question like I do

Comment: That's not really detailed enough. If you can come up with a more principled proposal, please post it on [meta].